# ga.js on server where my site is hosted

Tags: javascript, minify

I use the next code from Google for Analytics:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '############']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

And I use `minify` library for merging all JS files into the one. And I want to include ga.js to it. Can I use ga.js from my server and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you could use it from your server. Just download it and include it locally instead. It's even already minified. The thing is, you probably don't want to do that. Such a file is usually distributed from a CDN. There are a couple of advantages to this:

- If a lot of sites include it from there, chances are that your users will already have it in their cache and will not need to download it
- Those CDNs have distributed servers around the world. It will automatically download it from the closest source to your users, which is better than what you can guarantee with your server.
- You will also miss out on possible new features being added.

You can read [Google's word](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1032389) on that.

In short, juts leave it on GA's servers.

Comment: How often do they change that ga.js at Google — any statistics?

Comment: @SergikS not as far as I know, no.

Comment: Link was updated: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1032389